# matplotlib fill_between ignore areas of non sequential data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to fill the area under the curve where the y-value is 1.  The x-axis is a datetime array with non-regular values.  As you can see the fill also includes areas where there is no x-data.  Is there a way to tell fill_between to only fill "between" valid data? i.e. in the plot below I'd like the areas between "missing" samples to be white

```
tx = array(datetimes) # Array of irregular datetimes
ty = array([ones and zeros]) # Array of ones and zeros same size as tx

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(tx, ty, 'r.')
ax.fill_between(tx, 0, 1, where(ty==1))
```

[image: Filled_values]

Comment: How do you imaginge matplotlib to know at which points data is "missing"? Here, "missing" is your personal interpretation on the background of some imaginary pattern that you have in your head, but how should matplotlib know about it? In terms of a solution for your problem, please provide a [mcve] of the issue and pick an example from which you explain which data is "missing" and hence should not be filled.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're aiming for.

[image: filled areas]

If it is then you can use rectangular patches. In this code:

- `y` is the list of values meant to correspond to your 'irregular' pattern.
- `delta_float` measures the horizontal distance in the graph corresponding to `delta`, the distance between ticks.
- Notice that the patches are positioned and sized based on dates and `delta_float` units respectively.

---

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, HourLocator, DateFormatter, drange, date2num
from numpy import arange

date1 = datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 2)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 6)
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
dates = drange(date1, date2, delta)

delta_float = (dates[-1]-dates[0])/len(dates)

y = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, y, 'r.')
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((dates[0], 0), delta_float, 1, color='grey'))
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((dates[4], 0), 2*delta_float, 1, color='grey'))
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((dates[8], 0), delta_float, 1, color='grey'))
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((dates[12], 0), delta_float, 1, color='grey'))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator(arange(0, 25, 6)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

ax.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```